# How to get element within element?

Tags: jquery

I have a structure that looks like this:

```
<div class="project_group">
    <table>
        <tr style="display:none">
            <td>...</td>
        </tr>
        <tr style="display:none">
            <td>...</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>...</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

I have many different project_group `div`s in the page. Now, I want to iterate over each of these divs and get a count of the visible `tr`s. If the count is 0, then I want to hide the whole div.

```
$('div.project_group').each(function(index){
    if ($(this)[index].filter('table tr:visible').length > 0)
    {
        $(this)[index].show();
    }
    else
    {
        $(this)[index].hide();
    }
})
```

The error message I get:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object #<HTMLDivElement> has no method 'filter'
```

Comment: Just for fun I wrote a hide/show toggle for tables based on this :) http://jsfiddle.net/aWHKZ/1/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the [`find()`<sup>*[docs]*</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/find/) method if you don't have nested tables.

```
$(this).toggle( $(this).find('tr:visible').length );
```

...and I used the [`toggle()`<sup>*[docs]*</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) method to show or hide based on whether or not any matches were found. `0` means `hide`, greater than `0` means `show`.

Comment: This returns: `Uncaught TypeError: Object #<HTMLDivElement> has no method 'find'`

Comment: @Eric: Then you're doing `this.find(...` instead of `$(this).find(...`. The latter wraps your `<div>` in a jQuery object, from which you can call `.find()` and the other jQuery methods.

Comment: ...get rid of `[index]`. It is taking the `DOM` element that you placed in the jQuery object right back out (when index is `0` anyway).

Comment: Ha, yes. You are right. Thanks for this it is working nicely now. :) I will accept yours as the answer as soon as it allows me to. :)

Comment: *Glad it worked. Here's a little overview I wrote before your last comment showed up.* ...OK, you need to think of `$('div.project_group')` as a jQuery object that contains *n* number of elements that were found. Inside the `.each()` callback, `this` represents the current element in the iteration. So when you do `$(this)`, you're creating a *new jQuery object* that is separate from the original. This one only has *one* element in it (the one represented by `this`). Doing `$(this)[index]` when `index` equals `0` will pull the DOM element right back out of that jQuery object.

Comment: ...When `index` equals `1`, it will try to get the element at that index, but it doesn't exist, because remember, this jQuery object only has one item inside it.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. And now, I have to figure out race conditions. This is happening before another tasks finishes and so, doesn't toggle all the elements. But, I will go to the docs for this. :)

Answer (score 3):

How about a one liner:

```
$('div.project_group').not(':has(tr:visible)').hide();
```

Comment: This is nice! I deleted my answer 'couse of you! ;)  +1

Comment: This takes care of the `hide`, but not the `show`. You'd need a second filter.

Comment: The question itself only says to `hide` the elements, but the code sample also handles the inverse case. If the `show` is required then this is not a suitable solution.

Comment: Yep, you're right. I was focused more on the code than the text.

Answer (score 2):

There is no need to use `[index]` here, and use `.find` instead of `.filter`:

```
$('div.project_group').each(function(index){
    if ($(this).find('table tr:visible').length > 0)
        $(this).show();
    else
        $(this).hide();
})
```